# How to get the video file for a movie currently playing in browser?

Tags: video-capture

So I have a youtube page open where I can watch a video.

But this video was taken down by the user. My open page still has the video, if you go to it again (refresh) the new page does not.

Since I have the video loaded in my browser tab (chrome), how can I go about finding the actual file and saving it?

Comment: This question is probably off-topic for SO, but have you tried something [like this](http://techmarshal.blogspot.com/2011/07/copy-flv-file-from-firefox-chrome-or-ie.html)?

Comment: Appreciate the help but that did not work.

Comment: I'm still poking around in the temp and local folders, but I figured this question would be relevant since web developers should/need to know how to located all the objects part of the DOM yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the old days of YouTube, it may have been possible to find the single video file on your harddrive and save it, but this is no longer the case.  As explained in this [Computerphile video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqQk7kLuaK4), all YouTube videos are now split into tiny pieces and downloaded piece by piece.

You can observe this for yourself if you open up Chrome (or Firefox's) Dev Tools and watch the nnetwork tab.  You'll see:
[image: Pieces of Youtube video]
all of the pieces of the video loading bit by bit.

One additional thing you'll learn from the Network tab is that the videos are downloaded as octet streams, so you won't be able to find the links to the pieces hidden in the DOM.

One thing you migth try is, in the Network tab, clear the results and then move the cursor to the beginning of the video.  You should see the streams come up again.  Right click on the path name and then do a "save as", and save it as 0000.mp4 (or whatever), for all the pieces.  You should be able to reassemble these pieces in any video editing software.  I tested this by getting two pieces from a random YouTube video.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything that doesn't require a restart (and hence reload) of Chrome.

One (kludgy) hack if possible, though, would be to run a screen video capture and play the video.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this long back using IE6, i.e. fetch the file from the temporary files location and rename it to the extension flv.

The following links should point you in the right direction, but can't say it will work for sure, as I believe recent chrome versions seem to have a defensive cache implementation.

[Ubuntu Forum solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289003/where-does-chromium-keep-the-youtube-video-files)

You might need to tweak the above for your use.

Answer (score 0):

Run a screen recording/capture program such as:

- Screenr
- CamStudio

Then edit out the youtube bar if its visible.

Comment: This is not a good idea, as it involves recompression which produces reduced video quality.

Comment: Better than nothing if the video URL doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @LucasB if the site is down but the OPs system has it cached and is still able to play it, don't you think the movie is somewhere on his computer locally already? KevinL's answer suggests it's in pieces, but it would seem there may be some way to reassemble it rather than performing a screen grab.

Answer (score 0):

The buffered video is cached at the following location:

```
C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Temp\flaxxxx.tmp
```

Note you have to change  to whatever user you are using, and xxxx is a random number. Also, the .tmp file might be hidden, so make sure your windows explorer is displaying the hidden files.

While the tab is open, you won't be able to copy the file, but if you close it, the file will be automatically deleted. For doing so, [download HoboCopy](http://candera.github.io/hobocopy/), extract it and after that, run cmd as administrator. Change the directory on the console to the directory where you have extracted HoboCopy and type the following command:

```
hobocopy C:\users\<user name>\Appdata\Local\Temp C:\videos fla1234.tmp
```

**<user name>** - replace with your windows username

**C:\videos** - the directory where you want the video to be copied to

**fla1234.tmp** - the name of the file to be copied.

Wait for the copy to be done and then you can rename the destination file, changing '.tmp' to '.flv'. This file can be played with any FLV supporting media player.

Comment: Neither Chrome or Internet Explorer appears to dump any file in that folder. Furthermore, YouTube hasn't been using the FLV container for years except on legacy formats, so it would be surprising to see FLV files popping up instead of MP4.

Answer (score 0):

i find this software to get the video from temp files folder and play it http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html

Answer (score 0):

Video file is cached, therefore suggested ways can help you to save the file. But if you deal with same problems I offer using IDM(Internet Download Manager). After installation of this application for every online video stream (e.g. all flv files in youtube) IDM brings a small picture that you can click on it and downloading will be started automatically without need of any configuration.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install a browser extension to download YouTube videos. You won't find a simple URL for an `mp4` file in the HTML source. Try googling "youtube downloader" + your browser name.

As far as I recall, YouTube videos are not served as a continuous HTTP resource, but instead divided into small chunks and assembled client-side by the Flash player. This is why you can jump into the middle of a video, without having to buffer the first half of the video.

Generally speaking, YouTube don't want you to rip their content, so they aren't exactly making it easy for downloaders.

Comment: I think that since  the video was already removed from YouTube, downloading it is out of question.

Comment: If your download extension is loaded on the page where you have the video playing, it will probably also hold the information neccessary to fetch the video. If you don't keep your page open for days, downloads should work as deletions usually takes time to propagate out to the content delivery servers.